# CognitoUser Session: null after successful signIn

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

```
Auth.signIn({
    username, // Required, the username
    password, // Optional, the password
    validationData, // Optional, a random key-value pair map which can contain any key and will be passed to your PreAuthentication Lambda trigger as-is. It can be used to implement additional validations around authentication
}).then(user => console.log(user))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

So Im using AWS Amplify Auth.signIn

I succesfully sign in and get id-tokens, see the right username, and pool

But the session is null...

This is preventing me from using...Auth.VerifyCurrentUser

```
// To initiate the process of verifying the attribute like 'phone_number' or 'email'
Auth.verifyCurrentUserAttribute(attr)
.then(() => {
     console.log('a verification code is sent');
}).catch((e) => {
     console.log('failed with error', e);
});
```

I need Auth.VerifyCurrentUser to verify phone_number after verifying email

Why It gives me id-tokens and leaves me with a null session is confusing.

## Erros

Looking at the console I am seeing

POST https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ 400

POST https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ 400

Comment: Have you received an error? could you please share here?

Comment: POST : https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ 400

Comment: I believe it's not about the null session,`Auth.currentSession` is working for you, maybe you have roles, permissions, policies or trust issues.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not getting an error when calling `Auth.signIn`, check the content of `user.challengeName`.

```
const user = await Auth.signIn({
    username, // Required, the username
    password, // Optional, the password
    validationData,
})
```

If `user.challengeName` is `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED` you have to call

```
Auth.completeNewPassword(user, "newPassword");
```

You can read more about auth challenges [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/mfa/q/platform/js#sign-in-with-custom-auth-challenges).